# Print drawn lines on MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, printing

I'm drawing a barcode on a report with the method .line. When using pdfcreator the print is okay and using the function DoCmd.printOut and clicking on quick impression (print button) also.

But on normal printing after open report preview this barcode doesn't print.  =/

I tried changing resolution of printer, changing color of line, change printer and nothing.
There's one question alike here in stackoverflow without answer.

[Box drawn with line method on Access 2010 report displaying in print preview but not actually printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035638/box-drawn-with-line-method-on-access-2010-report-displaying-in-print-preview-but)

Any solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried using an actual barcode font?  No special coding required and it acts like most any other font as far as your printer is concerned. For example:
http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/

Comment: I dont have admin rights on the pc of my work to install fonts neither to update the printer driver.

Comment: Can you change the dpi of the print job?  If so, set it to 300.

Comment: Nope, my printer minimun dpi is 600dpi O.o